# How to save data into application vb.net ? (Not use database or txt file)

Tags: vb.net

I a newbie in VB.net. I have a small project that save data from textbox. (just simple: create textbox, fill my name to textbox and save it).

But I don't want use database or txtfile because if I use like that, I will have 2 file: my app.exe and database file. I don't know whether there have anyway to save data into this my app.exe. Just have 1 file app.exe, database is included in this app (App is same to excel file: just have 1 file excel which can fill data and save)

Comment: Excel have two files. `Excel.exe` and `yourdata.xlsx` - so seems even Microsoft can not save data inside one .exe file :)

Comment: Hi Fabio, Thank for your answer. I mean just one file mydata.xlsx. Before, I use 1 file .xlsx to fill data, save data, program macro to handle data. Everthing are used in 1 file .xlsx. But now, I would like to create app the same with .xlsx file. Is there any way to do like that or I had to use database to save data.

Comment: You can use same approach as Excel do. Create application (.exe) file which can open files with `.mydata` extension. So you will have application which can open, create and modify `.mydata` files.

Comment: That sound like a greate idea but What is .mydata file? Could you please tell me more detail about it, sample or give me some keyword, I can search google for it.

Comment: `.mydata` - is an example - you can use any extension you want. File will contain data in any format you want. Search for "Open files with custom extension"

Comment: Yes, let's me research about it . So many thank to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you have a class `Student` (from your comment)

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

For binding to `DataGridView` you can use `BindingList<Student>`.

Then when you close your application save in JSON format.

```
var data = _yourBindingList.ToList();
var serializedData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"fileName.anyExtensionYouWant", serializedData);
```

When application starts load data from the file and deserialize it.

```
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"fileName.anyExtensionYouWant", serializedData);
var loadedStudents = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(data);

_yourBindingList = new BindingList(loadedStudents);
yourDataGridView.DataSource = _yourBindingList;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to save the text to a txt file

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/27t17sxs(v=vs.90).aspx

So

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt", "This is new text to be added.", False)
```

on your're case can be

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestFolder1\test.txt", textbox1.text, False)
```

If you need to use MyDocuments or Desktop folders you need to use relative system routes

Comment: Save and read from text file is a great idea but I cannot extend it for my project. because I have more than 1 data field (Ex: Student name, Student ID, Student Age...). When I save it to text file, it really hard for me to get data and using binding data to show each student's information to datagridview

Comment: The original post was "(just simple: create textbox, fill my name to textbox and save it)." I just think about a simple textbox

You can concatenate the fields using a special character like "|" and then use the full string to take each part. Is ok for you?

Something like textbox1.text & "|" textbox2.text & "|" & textbox3.text